# How do I have a batch file check for 64-bit OS and an installed library and application?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a batch file (for Windows OS) that when it runs, it first must check if the operating system is 32- or 64-bit, and if Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (x84 or x64) 10.0.40219 is installed on the computer. 
If it isn't installed then run the vcredist_x32 or vcredist_x64.
It also must check if the application LibraChildren exist and if so uninstall it.

Comment: The proper way to check if the Visual C++ runtime is installed and install it if necessary, is to just run `vcredist_x32` and `vcredist_x64`. They'll refuse to install if they're already installed or if not supported by the OS.

Comment: Dear Ross thanks for your response and your corrections in my text.
The solution you suggest looks good. I will use this if I cant finally do what I described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

i solve your problem with batch-file and powershell

first  create start.bat
includ:

```
powershell -noexit "& ""s:\1.ps1"""
```

second save this script as 1.ps1

```
wmic os get osarchitecture#first for check os architecture 

$a=( Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product | Select-Object -Property Name )
if ( $a | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010" ) {echo "exist"} else { s:\1.bat }#this check programm microsoft visual installed or not
```

third
go create 1.bat
include:
`msiexec vcredist_x32 or vcredist_x64`

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is little complicated. But it's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I create a solution with in batch file.
Here is the code:

```
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\" (
   if not exist C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll ( vcredist_x64 )  
   ) 
else (    
   if not exist C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcr100.dll ( vcredist_x86 )
)`
```

in win32 works well, but I don't know if it is works well in win64`